# Difference between Python dynamic field lookup

Tags: python

What's the difference (if any) between

```
model.__dict__['title_en']
```

and

```
model.__getattribute__('title_en')
```

and what's best practice ?

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ : thxs for the edit, you are a machine ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice? Use [getattr](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/getattr.html).

```
getattr(model, 'title_en')
```

You only want `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` when you want to [override](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) the default attribute fetching mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, the [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr) built-in is the right way to get an attribute (in general you don't access Python special methods directly: you access them through built-ins and operators!).

`getattr` does a lot more than a lookup in the object's `__dict__`: it supports properties and other descriptors, attributes inherited from the class and its bases (such as methods), attributes that may be dynamically generated via a `__getattr__` method (in the object's class, or, again, one of its bases).  Just like direct access `model.title_en` does, when you know the name at the time you're writing the code (in which case of course you wouldn't use `getattr`;-).  This makes it **by far** the preferred way of accessing an attribute whose name you "learn" only dynamically!

Answer (score 1):

The first won't work because `__dict__` is supposed to be a dictionary, not a function. And the correct way is `getattr(model, 'title_en')`.

Comment: right. I meant to use bracket which works but thanks ofr pointing this out.